# Why is this a duplicate question when I didn't know to ask about the subject of the second post?

Tags: discussion

Why is this question a duplicate? [Python evaluating/compiling a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821303/python-evaluating-compiling-a-string)

There are only the same in the way that a teacup and donut are the same topologically. I had no comprehension that the getattr function was available and applicable to my situation.  How can I ask a question about something that I don't even know exists?  If we want to be pedantic, which seems to be the order of the day, then quite clearly the answer IS similar, but NOT the question.

I believe my "teacup" style question adds value to future searches.  In fact I've come across many questions with answers that I know instinctively contain the answer to my question but since I'm looking at the question from a different viewpoint, the solution escapes me.

Seriously folks.

Comment: Kafka is laughing his ass off

Comment: Seriously, what's your beef with making your post a sign-post if a good duplicate exists? The way you explain it, they are essentially the same once you know it...

Comment: Duplicates aren't a bad thing. Your question will now help other users find the getattr solution. You don't lose any points. This is a good thing.

Comment: "my 'teacup' style question adds value to future searches." Yes, exactly! That's why the duplicate closure process must link to a good answer.

Comment: See also on Meta.SE: [Why are questions closed as duplicates if you could have never found them without knowing the answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181864)

Comment: Not to mention https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/. Yes, seriously.

Comment: Feels like there is meta question that should come out of this one: how to better explain users that duplicate is positive resolution of the questions.

Comment: @dpetican I'm interested why you believed that duplicate is negative thing. Do you mind sharing your thought in sentence or two on it?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well, in the vast majority of cases, a duplicate *isn't* a positive resolution of a question.  There are rare cases where a problem looks radically different from another problem, while still being the same underlying problem, or where issues aren't discoverable, but in the vast majority of cases the author just didn't bother to find the duplicate when they should have, and them posting it was just being a drain on the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this a duplicate question when I didn't know to ask about the subject of the second post?

Why is the fact that you didn't know how to find the duplicate make it not a duplicate?

> I believe my "teacup" style question adds value to future searches.

Then the system is working properly.  Users searching on your wording of the problem will find your quesiton, and be directed to the existing answer that they may have struggled to find otherwise.

The system works.

Comment: Well okay, maybe I don't understand the point of marking a question as a duplicate.  So what exactly happens to my question in the system when its marked as a duplicate?  Is it less visible from a recent point of view.  In other words if I ask a question and its immediately marked as duplicate is it less likely to be answered?  Although the answer in the other post was comprehensible to me as I pointed out there are situation where its not.  Then what do I do having asked a "duplicate question" but not understanding the original answer?

Comment: @dpetican When it's marked as a duplicate you have an answer in the duplicate, the act of marking it as a duplicate *is answering it*.  You can't have a duplicate that *doesn't* have an answer, since you have the duplicate in the answer.  If your question is closed and you feel the answers there don't solve your problem, clarify the question to explain what about the answer(s) there don't solve your problem.

Comment: Perhaps I'm taking "explain how its different" in the wrong way.  Since its been almost canonically stated that the question is a duplicate, then the invitation to refute that would seem futile.  Also, discussion seems to be abhorrent on SO so I don't think I can ask: "okay, but how do I apply this to my specific problem which is xyz"?  Perhaps "explain how its different" should be rephrased to something else.  And yes the act of marking a question as duplicate and the phrasing of the explanation lead me, a "newbie" to feel, well not snubbed, but at a loss as to what to do next.

Comment: @dpetican why do you think you need to do *anything* next? It sounds like you've got the answer you needed (use `getattr`), so is there still a question? *"If those answers do not fully address your question"* then action is needed but, in this case, they *do*. Applying that basic information to your specific problem is **your job**, we don't want to rewrite the same information for every possible combination of class and attribute names!

Comment: Yes the getattr is all I need but I'm not just talking about this one question.  Its only an example.  However, its not a frequent thing.  I get great help on SO.  Thanks. I'm just trying to learn how the answerers on SO think so I can ask better questions.  Also, I am not in the CompSci group of programmers.  I went to community college (a Canadian thing) not university.  So, what I'm saying is that in the case(s) where I think it doesn't help to mark my posts duplicates the indicated answer tends to be a little bit more abstract and theoretical IMHO.

Comment: @dpetican And you were specifically told that if the answer to the duplicate doesn't answer your question, you simply need to edit the question to clarify how it fails to answer your question.

Comment: Okay.  'nuff said.  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 4):

> I believe my "teacup" style question adds value to future searches.

To enlarge on JDB's point a bit more: your question adds value *best* **by being marked as a duplicate**. That's the entire reason we even have that feature.

There is nothing inherently wrong with duplicates; we're not trying to lay a guilt trip on you or passive-aggressively snub you. They're there for efficiency.

Comment: To elaborate on the impression aspects of having a question marked duplicate I would say that in general something that is marked as duplicate can be considered redundant and open to deletion.  Of course this doesn't happen on SO, but not knowing any better, one might think so.